# Integral Closure, Galois extension,and Dedekind Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let
$A$: Dedekind domain, $K$: $\operatorname{Frac}(A)$, $B$: Dedekind domain with $A \subset B$, $L$: $\operatorname{Frac}(B)$

Let $L/K$: galois extension with galois group: $G$.

$B^G=\{b \in B \mid \sigma(b)=b \text{ for all } \sigma \in G\}=A$
$\implies B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$

Is this true?
I already prove the converse, but not sure if this holds.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it's not true. Try to take B=A. Then the fixed ring is A, but unless the extension is trivial, this is not the integral closure.

Comment: when A=B, then L=K. Since A is dedekind, A is integrally closed and B(=A) is the integral closure of A in L holds, i think.

Comment: I don't think I understood what you say. The claim you want to prove, as I understand it, is that if B is a subring of L, for which the fixed ring under the action of G is A, then B is the integral closure. It is not the true if you take B=A. If I got you wrong, please explain what you wanted to prove :)

Comment: you understand it right. but i do not get that it does not hold when B=A. when B=A,the extension L/K is trivial, which leads to the conclusion. i think. please tell me if i get something wrong.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, I didn't notice you write that L is the fraction field of B. Ignore what I wrote, you are write thar if B=A then L=K.

Comment: maybe my explanation was a bit complicated. apologize for that.  back to the problem; let C the integral closure of A in L, then I already proved C^G=A. then C^G=B^G. does it follow that C=B?

Comment: I think the two points are : $B$ is a Dedekind domain implies $B$ is integrally closed and $B = \sigma(B), \sigma \in G$. So $B^G = A$ implies that $\prod_{\sigma \in G}(x-\sigma(b))$ is monic in $A[x]$ and that $B$ contains the integral closure of $A \subset B$.

Comment: @reuns I think you don't necessarily have $\sigma(B) = B$. A possible counterexample is given below.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true.

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension of number field, let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$ that splits into more than one primes in $\mathcal{O}_L$:
$$\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L = \mathfrak{P}_1 \cdots \mathfrak{P}_r$$

Let $A = (\mathcal{O}_K)_{\mathfrak{p}}$, the localization at $\mathfrak{p}$ and $B = (\mathcal{O}_L)_{\mathfrak{P}_1}$. Both are Dedekind domains. It is easily seen that $B^G = A$, but the integral closure of $A$ in $L$ is the localization of $\mathcal{O}_L$ at all $\mathfrak{P}_1, \cdots, \mathfrak{P}_r$, which is a proper subset of $B$.

Comment: So $K = \mathbf{Q}, L = \mathbf{Q}(i),p=5= (2+i)(2-i), A=\mathbf{Z}_{(5)} = \{\frac{u}{v}, (u,v) \in \mathbf{Z}^2, 5 \nmid v \}$, $B =  \mathbf{Z}[i]_{(2+i)} = \{\frac{u}{v}, (u,v) \in \mathbf{Z}[i]^2, v \not \in (2+i)\mathbf{Z}[i] \}$, $\sigma(c+id) = c-id, G= \{\sigma^2,\sigma\}$ then $\frac1{5^n} \not \in B$ so $B^G = \mathbf{Z}_{(5)}$ but $\frac{2+i}{5}=\frac{1}{2-i} \in B$ is not integral over $\mathbf{Z}_{(5)}$. $A,B$ are Dedekind domains since they have only one prime ideal. The problem is that $\sigma(B) \ne B$.

Comment: And replacing $B$ by $\bigcap_{\sigma \in G} \sigma(B)$ makes the claim true